# Can't a website/server owner read the passwords out before hashing?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I just read many articles about hashing and that client-side hashing is not necessary when using SSL.

So I have a website where I hash passwords with bcrypt i.e. salting.
But I can just read out the passwords plain-text before hashing.
(In my case just: `console.log(req.body.password`)

How I can prevent this?

Comment: If you don't trust the server, why do you register. Anyway, read [PAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement). And this is off-topic here. Ask in information security where there are already Q/A

Comment: Even if you hash it client side, the malicious site owner can just read it with JavaScript before you do. `console.log(document.getElementById("password").value)` isn't much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, why would you.

You are the site owner and responsible for such actions. Of course you can just add such lines to your code and receive all the information and no, there is no way to prevent it. On every site you register, the clear-text password will always be passed to the code at some point.

People do fix such trust issues, by using a password manager, which randomly generates a good password.